# SQL query is returning one result less than expected

Tags: android, android-sqlite

my query keeps returning one result less than expected. Initialy I had 6 rows that needed to be returned, it kept returning only 5, I decided to add another one and now it is returning 6 instead of 7, It is always the last one.
I tested the same query in SQLite Admin and it worked just fine.

```
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Activities JOIN 
       UserMakesActivities ON UserMakesActivies.ActivityID = 
       Activities.intID WHERE UserMakesActivies.UserID = " + ID, null);
```

Any ideas are welcome. If for some reason the sql is not correct it is because I changed it to make it clearer here.

Edit: as requested this is where I am moving my cursor.

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    Log.i("tag", "contagem " + cursor.getCount());
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Atividade atividade = cursorToAtividade(cursor);
        atividades.add(atividade);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

private static Atividade cursorToAtividade(Cursor cursor) {
    Atividade atividade = new Atividade();
    atividade.setNum(cursor.getInt(0));
    atividade.setNome(cursor.getString(1));
    atividade.setInformacao(cursor.getString(2));
    atividade.setAtividadeFeita((cursor.getInt(3) == 1) ? true : false);
    atividade.setAtividadeMonitorada((cursor.getInt(4) == 1) ? true :    false);
    atividade.setTempo(cursor.getInt(5));
    atividade.setTipo(cursor.getString(6));
    return atividade;
}
```

Comment: How do you know how many are returned? Show us this code.

Comment: Log.i("tag", "contagem " + cursor.getCount()); return 5 out of 6 or 6 ou of 7

Comment: Is it possible that there a duplicate record in your table?

Comment: No, I already checked that and the creation and insertion of values in the table is working as it should.

Comment: Can you provide more code? Perhaps where you are moving through the Cursor.

Comment: It is now showing how I am moving my cursor around

Comment: When I removed the DISTINCT it doubles the output but it is still missing the last activity

Comment: Obviously that activity doesn't exist. Can you pull the DB and try on PC with an SQLite client?

Comment: Can you link me to a place where I can learn to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found a way to check my DB using SQLite Manager plugin for android that I got from [here](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/18/sqlitemanager-plugin-for-eclipse/)

There was an error in the database and with that info I understood what I was doing wrong when submiting info to the DB

Answer (score 0):

This may not fix your issue, but I see a few suspicious things in there.

First, it would be better to use selectionArgs for your query:

```
String[] selectionID = new String[] {ID};
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Activities JOIN 
       UserMakesActivities ON UserMakesActivies.ActivityID = 
       Activities.intID WHERE UserMakesActivies.UserID = ?", selectionID );
```

Also make sure that you close your cursor to avoid memory leaks.

```
  if (cursor != null){
    Log.i("tag", "contagem " + cursor.getCount());
    for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Atividade atividade = cursorToAtividade(cursor);
        atividades.add(atividade);

    }
   cursor.close();
   }
```

Comment: Thx for your suggestions but the first one did not work and I was already closing the cursor just forgot to post =/

Comment: `while(cursor.moveToNext())` is enough. `Cursor` should be closed on a `finally` block, otherwise if an exception happens it would not be closed. And `query` **never** returns a null `Cursor`, so checking for null is useless.